# Грузить свой или чужой?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, webbrowser

Всем доброго времени суток.  Вопрос такой.
Например, 2 способа подгрузки библиотек.

1. `<link href="//yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
2. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery-ui.css">`

В чем отличия? (понятно что будет, если сервер отвалится)

Но в остальном?  Лучше кеширует? (как бы не думаю).

Расскажите разницу и направьте на верный путь.

Comment: плюс использования cdn в том, что их много кто использует, следовательно, данная библиотека _уже может быть в кэше_ при первом заходе.

Comment: Старайтесь использовать как можно меньше подключений к сторонним сервисам + как можно меньше подключать js и css файлов в своих проектах. Это напрямую влияет на скорость загрузки страниц.

Comment: Вот  2 ответа и 2 разных  и  с то и то правда по сути но  есть тут кто тестил  подобный вопрос  по факту что мы получаем? .   нужный  факты ребятки

Comment: Свой сервер всегда под контролем. А yastatic сегодня есть, завтра нет, и твой сайтик неожиданно перестает работать. А уж ежели кто-то зловреда подставит, вот тогда ещё веселей будет. `Верить, в наше время, нельзя никому, даже себе. Мне - можно!`